# GooglePlus Like Layout unlike waterflow style layout

Tags: android

I want to do GooglePlus on Android. I know iOS have some open source which can be used to show the data based on their content-size and by maintaining the row linear, but I cannot search Android. I want to do it, but I do not know where to start. Can you give me some advice and links?

[image: https://github.com/RATTLESNAKE-VIPER/GLGooglePlusLikeLayout/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%203.png]

Comment: I guess what you need is ScrollView (for scrolling) containing a GridLayout (not GridView). Check this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Comment: what do you mean by "maintaining the row linear"?

Comment: @ Vasily Sochinsky  GridLayout not used for sdk2.x

Comment: In android there is a [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html), containing backports to 2.x android versions. GridLayout is there. Check this one: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1395

Comment: so was that what you need?